# Value is not a convertible object

Tags: dapper

I have a simple query and Poco that I'm using with Dapper like so:

`var jc = this.dbConnection.ExecuteScalar<JcUser>("SELECT loginid as Username,Password,coalesce(CustomerId,0) as CustomerId,TextProfileId,UxProfileId from \"user\" where id = @id", new {id = id});`

Poco:

```
public class JcUser
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }

    public int TextProfileId { get; set; }

    public int UxProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

When this executes it throws an exception with the message

`Value is not a convertible object: System.String to JcUser`

The stack trace ends up at: `at System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type)`

Any ideas why its doing this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: Using `var jc = this.dbConnection.Query<JcUser>("SELECT loginid as Username,Password,coalesce(CustomerId,0) as CustomerId,TextProfileId,UxProfileId from \"user\" where id = @id", new {id = id}).First();` appears to work. I also realise I'm a moron and ExecuteScalar is only for one value. However, is my update the best way to retrieve only one row?

Comment: A column/property called `Password`?  *Think of the kittens!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` maps to the ADO.NET method of the same name. It returns at most one cell: one grid, one row, one column. As such, it is not intended for use with complex objects, and **cannot** work correctly in your case as you have multiple columns.

Dapper assumes you would only use that with simple types like `int`,  `string` etc.

In your case, use:

```
var jc = this.dbConnection.Query<JcUser>(
     sql, args).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want to avoid a hidden `List<>` allocation you could also pass `buffered: false`.